# what is smaclmgr port, what does it mean?

Tags: unix, port

port 4660 description shows a name smaclmgr.

What does smaclmgr port means?

what is the full form of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I noticed it only just now somewhere in a relation to USB DISK network mapping, but if can also be something macintosh (apple) specific for that as mac is in the name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).